# AngularJS + expressJS - single page app + injecting templates dynamically

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am working on a angularJS + nodejs/expressjs application.

When the user accesses the url of the application I want to check if user is already logged-in or not and if so show him the homepage of the application
Otherwise, redirect the user to login page of the application.

By homepage I mean a page which is based on the role of the user. So, that will be determined based on values in database.

I assume we have one full html page (index.html) which would be sent to browser along with other partial pages.
So, when user accesses the homepage without having logged-in I need to inject partial-login.html into index.html and show the user login  page. 
if login successful, again inject homepage.html to index.html.
If user is already logged-in then inject partial-homepage.html in index.html and show the user the page.

In expressJS route I have a route for "/" to return index.html. But, not sure how I can inject different partials based on the above scenarios. Can someone help me on this.

Comment: ng-include takes parameterized html path.. use that

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You need to use session middleware.</strike>

https://github.com/expressjs/session

When user logs in,store his name in session variable and when user opens your website again check whether that variable has value assigned or not.If not means user has logged out and needs to login and render him the login page.

Also,dont forget to **destroy** session when user clicks log out

If you are using jade,use if/else conditions in it. When you check if user has session token on server-side,then send the variable value as true to the jade template upon render..else false and show the login page accordingly (placing login form inside else condition in your template )

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am aware of using a session variable. My question is , since it is a single page app, we need to inject the login page as one of the partials into the main html page. This part is what I am not clear.